# Why do input functions like readline() and scan() include code when scanning for inputs? How to fix?

Tags: r, input

If I run,

```
input <- as.integer(scan(what = "integer"))
```

I get no problems, but

```
input <- scan(what = "integer")
#Anything here, including whitespace
```

Now input incudes the "#Anything here" as part of the input, and trying to as.integer() it gives me an NA. (If nmax=1, it automatically reads that as the input and doesn't allow any more.)
How is this preventable? What am I doing wrong?

Only works when you run the individual input line all by itself, give the input, then run the rest by itself. Should run code until input function is called, then give an input interface, THEN include the rest of the code. I am using RStudio.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, please give us a bigger picture, use case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In RStudio, use Source to read the input the way you want.  Using Ctrl-Enter or Run simulates pasting it into the console (which means text following the `scan()` is assumed to be input).

So this works with Ctrl-Enter:

```
input <- scan(what = integer())
3

#Anything here, including whitespace
```

and the input ends up containing 3.  (`what` should be an example of the type you want, not the name of it.  So use `integer()` if you want an integer result.)

This works with Source:

```
input <- scan(what = integer())
#Anything here, including whitespace
```

and will prompt you to enter the number.